# Will removing code from specs alter the actual application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've inherited some legacy code. For some reason, inside a controller spec file -- right underneath `require "spec_helper"` is something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # controller actions
end
```

Is this code affecting the application? Can it safely be removed, or at least moved to the actual `ApplicationController` where it belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is generally not really something I would encourage, I assume they change `ApplicationController` code to make testing easier. E.g. a piece of code to remove authentication (overriding the behaviour in the rails application).

So my guess is:

- removing this code will break your tests
- moving this code to the real `ApplicationController` will break your app.

Without more details as to what the code does, it would be hard to say more. But my assumption now is to just leave the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Specs are tests, which sit in the `spec` directory. Application code lives in the `app` directory, and does not use anything in `spec`. So you can safely remove that class without affecting the application.